# How to correct the disappeared view button in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am new to **Drupal**. Under appearance > setting > garland >Toggle display I unchecked some check box like logo, site name etc.... That made **view button** in the all the pages to disappear but **edit** is displaying correctly.  After that,I reverted back the changes. View button is not appearing but if we click the area of view button area its navigating the view link. Please help me out.. Thanks in advance

[see this image for reference](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-In2n-IOPGnOUttOUR3anBmbTQ/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You should always clear your cache after changing the apperence of Drupal. To do this: *Administer > Site configuration/Development > Performance*

And you should really invest some time in reading how Drupal works. A good start is: [User and Builder Guides](http://drupal.org/documentation)